# Pass arguments to constructor

Tags: solidity, remix

I got a constructor like this:

```
contract Test{
    constructor(uint256 _num) public {
    num = _num
    ;}
}
```

Now I want to use this contract in another contract. Like this:

```
contract Call{
Test test;

   function addTest(address addr){
      test = Test(addr)
   }
}
```

How can I pass the Argument _num to the constuctor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]You can pass the argument _num to the constructor as follows:

```
contract Test {
    uint public num;
    constructor(uint256 _num) public {
        num = _num;
    }
}

contract Call {
    Test test;
    function addTest(uint256 _newNum){
        test = new Test(_newNum)
    }
}
```

Please go through [Creating contracts via **new** keyword](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=constructor#creating-contracts-via-new)

The above link will help you in understanding things better.

Answer (score 1):

While another answer showing the use of the `new` keyword was accepted, I don't believe it directly addressed the fundamental misconception in the posed question.

The key is to realize `test = Test(addr)` is not a use of the constructor.

That's why you can't pass any constructor args.  It's actually an explicit cast of an address to a contract.  A new contract is only created with, well, `new`.